# What do I do with error code 404 with npm (new to coding)

Tags: npm, error-handling, http-status-code-404, npm-scripts

I’m trying to code this and it keeps saying
npm ERR! code e404
npm ERR! 404 not found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/orc-space-api-wrapper - not found

npm ERR! ‘orc-space-api-wrapper@*’ is not in this registry.

I was trying to download this thing for a discord bot the tutorial was on YouTube this was the video https://youtu.be/Qqog9HaNU8Y?si=uVqQrXhwwNFO4LBv

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.